# Defining cross project versions for gradle build

Tags: gradle

I have a several projects in a flat structure with dependencies between them.

Currently in each one a have a definition similar to this defining the versions used within the build script:

```
ext {
    versions = [
        scala:     '2.11.1',
        scalatra:  '2.3.0',
        jetty:     '9.1.5.v20140505',
        scalaTest: '2.3.0',
        junit:     '4.8.1',
    ]
}
```

and later usage:

```
compile group:'org.scala-lang' , name:'scala-library',version: versions.scala
```

As I have this defined in each `build.gradle` what I would rather want is to define the versions in one place and read in all files in the current build.
Writing to a global value will not be sufficient here as the combination of build files involved in a build may change (e.g. when testing a specific component only none of the components depending on it will be defined)

Comment: It can be set in a external script file the will be executed with `Eval` and return a map of dependencies. For me there're far too little details to give a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put this map into its own `.gradle` file and include into your projects with `apply from: '../dependencies.gradle'`. Similar to what Gradle has in its [own codebase](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/gradle/dependencies.gradle)